# Автообновление скрипта

Tags: php

Есть скрипт, который ежесекундно должен присылать информацию о состоянии сервера. Сейчас это работает CTL+R. Как автоматизировать? CRON не подходит, мин. время - 1 минута, это слишком много.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Запускайте скрипт по крону раз в минуту, а внутри скрипта отправляйте данные N раз каждую 1/N минуты с помощью sleep.

Answer (score 0):

Если сервер присылает информацию на веб-страницу, то, может, проще сделать автообновление на клиентской стороне? На JavaScript же можно прописать запрос состояния сервера. Или присылание информации о состоянии сервера заключается в запуске утилиты на том же сервере? Тогда скрипт с циклом, запускающий утилиту и делающий паузу.